# how to modify global resource dll's without compiling the code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, app-globalresources

I have separated my Global resource files to a different class library in my project solution.
If in case after moving to production, i wanna modify some resource values or if i wanna add new resource file for a new country, then is it possible to modify my current resource dll?
Is there any software tools available? if yes please let me know the tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always replace the DLL however, if the public API of the resource assembly changes. You'll break your code. The JIT compilation that does the actual binding occurs at runtime and because of this it's *typically always* safe to replace the assembly with one that has additional members but only if your **not** using some kind of versioning or strongly named assemblies.

You don't need to recompile or link stuff with .NET but you'll have to rebuild your resource assemblies. The .NET Framework SDK contains tools for this.

You can use resgen.exe as well as the C# compiler with the `/resource:` flag to link, build or embed resources.